# Databinding JSONP with angular

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, jsonp

So I'm making calls to an API and I'm receiving data in JSONP format. I'm trying to bind this data using angular data binding such as ng-bind or using double brackets and so forth.
however, for each object I receive I get an image code that is a full html tag like so:

```
[object]
description: "this is a description"
image_code:"<img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/p.image.slated.com/film/67/25/59510/1_small.jpg?get=1398992737'>"
```

Does anyone have any idea as to how I would bind it so that for each object i would bind the src with the given image code?

I've tried it like this

```
<img ng-src={{object.image_code}}>
```

but its not working. Any help or thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So, after looking for a little bit more and trying to figure it out. binding the image link to the div using sanitize worked out really well. I think it was the best way to do this for my purposes. I just used sanitize and did an ng-bind-html to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
<img ng-src="{{object.image_code}}">
```

`{{object.image_code}}` should be wrapped inside `" "` but apparently missing in your code.

plnkr [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Hx7B9/2/)

Comment: there would be not affect by wrapping it up inside " ".

Answer (score 0):

As your object is having image as a string. You need to extract the url part of it in your controller.

```
data = {
description : "something",
image_code : "<img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/p.image.slated.com/film/67/25/59510/1_small.jpg?get=1398992737'>"
};
```

Then in controller use regular expression to extract the url part.

```
$scope.image_url = data.image_code.match(/http.*(?=')/g).join();
```

now your $scope.image_url will have: `"https://s3.amazonaws.com/p.image.slated.com/film/67/25/59510/1_small.jpg?get=1398992737"` as the value.

Now you can use it as:

`<img ng-src="{{image_code}}">`